# Returning wrong md5 hash in jni

Tags: android, c, hash, java-native-interface, md5

I'm trying to generate MD5 hash for a string using the original/untouched md5.h and md5c.c (github source file: https://github.com/sinhpn92/encryption-in-C/tree/master/app/src/main/cpp). But my result is not right at anytime. When i use samsung galaxy j device for test, my result is right. But when i use samsung galaxy s7 device for test, my result is wrong. What's wrong in my code? Have any suggestion for resolve this problem? Thank your support.

This is my project: https://github.com/sinhpn92/encryption-in-C

I use cmake to config jni lib:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.4.1)

set(MD5SOURCES
    src/main/cpp/md5.c)


add_library(native-lib
             SHARED
             src/main/cpp/native-lib.cpp
              ${MD5SOURCES})


find_library(log-lib
              log )

target_link_libraries(native-lib
                       ${log-lib} )
```

And this is native-lib:

```
#include <jni.h>
#include <string>
#include "md5.h"

extern "C"
jstring
Java_test_sinhpn_md5test_MainActivity_stringFromJNI(JNIEnv *env, jobject /* this */, jstring data) {
    char *cstr = (char *) (env)->GetStringUTFChars(data, 0);

    MD5_CTX context = {0};
    MD5Init(&context);
    MD5Update(&context, (unsigned char *) cstr, strlen(cstr));
    unsigned char dest[16] = {0};
    MD5Final(dest, &context);
    env->ReleaseStringUTFChars(data, cstr);

    int i;
    char destination[32] = {0};
    for (i = 0; i < 16; i++) {
        sprintf(destination, "%s%02x", destination, dest[i]);
    }
    return env->NewStringUTF(destination);
}
```

My build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "test.sinhpn.md5test"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        externalNativeBuild {
            cmake {
                cppFlags "-frtti -fexceptions"
            }
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    externalNativeBuild {
        cmake {
            path "CMakeLists.txt"
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.1.1'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

This is result of my test:

[image]

[image]

Comment: It would be worthwhile to verify that the behavioral difference is not attributable to a flaw in your third-party MD5 library.  I suggest testing that library on a few byte sequences expressed explicitly (and numerically) in C source to confirm that it produces the same results on both systems.

Comment: This looks problematic in the MD5 code you posted:  `/* UINT4 defines a four byte word */
typedef unsigned long int UINT4;`  That won't be true on a 64-bit platform with 64-bit `long` values....

Comment: @John Bollinger: Thank your comment. 
I understand your suggest that I must test with a few byte, not with a string? Right?

Comment: @Andrew Henle Thank your comment. So my md5 lib wrong? could you please share for me good md5 code?

Comment: @PhanSinh have you found the solution?can you please mention how to resolve this issue?

Comment: @OmInfowaveDevelopers: yeap. i have resolved. You can see my answer below

Comment: @PhanSinh can you please share updated code on github?  or update right resolution here on stackoverflow it will be helpfull

Comment: @AndoMasahashi I did update. Please try again on my github.

Comment: @Phansinh sure let me check

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have resolved my problem by replace:

`typedef unsigned long int UINT4;` in md5.c -> `typedef uint32_t UINT4;`.

I tested again on two device and it's work fine. On a 64 bits machine long int are (usually) 64 bits long instead of 32

Comment: worked when i remove long from this typedef unsigned long int UINT4;   and now it look like typedef unsigned int UINT4 this , now working thanks for moving me right direaction

Answer (score 0):

the two phones use different ARM instruction sets. 
Galaxy J uses armeabi-v7a, while S7 uses arm64-v8a.

the cmake as per your above builds is making the .so file for all architectures and this causes the issue because of 32 bit vs 64 bit cast conversion issues in the native code.

however, there exists a simple fix in your case. you could restrict the build to abiFilters "armeabi-v7a", "armeabi", in your default config like below

```
    externalNativeBuild {
        cmake {
            cppFlags "-frtti -fexceptions"
            abiFilters "armeabi-v7a", "armeabi"
        }
    }
```

this should still work, because the arm64v8a is backward compatible with the older v7a architecture.

Comment: The architecture difference is an important observation, but do you see any *actual* cast conversion issues in the native code, or is that part speculative?

Comment: @Bharat Kumar Molleti: Thank your comment. But it's not work.

Comment: @JohnBollinger please see andrew's comment above.  /* UINT4 defines a four byte word */ typedef unsigned long int UINT4; That won't be true on a 64-bit platform with 64-bit long values..., with issues as above its advisable to be careful with these kind of conversions and casts.

Comment: @BharatKumarMolleti, so it was indeed speculative, but your speculation turns out to be correct?  I commend you for your insight.  It would have been a better answer, however, if it had pointed out the actual issue with reference to the problematic code instead of guessing at the general nature of the problem.